# create new password for a user which one's password is already removed

Tags: 12.04

I recently removed my user password and now when i want to install any software or do something major, it wants a password. I thought that removing password would also remove sudo password. Now i need your help to remove all passwords or recover my last password. My best regards.

Answer (score 2):

How exactly did you remove the password, did you edit the /etc/shadow file?
Is it making you enter a password, or can you just hit enter without putting any pass into the box?

What you could do is set a new password and then edit the /etc/shadow file to have a blank space for the password. All you need to do on the password prompts would be to hit enter.

This post is quite helpful to change the password: https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/65957